# stock a value of a JSON field into a variable

Tags: json, typescript

i want to stock **count** value from json object into a variable to work with it, here is my json object :

```
{
  "actionList": {
    "count": 35
    // ...
   }
}
```

and here is my Http call :

```
this._http.get(uriG, requestOption).
  map(res => {return res.json()})
    .subscribe(result =>{ 
      this.actionsG = result;
```

So actionG has the JSON object containts, i wanna get the count value, i've tried geting it like this :

```
count = this.actionG.actionList.count
```

right now i'm doing it with substring like this :

```
this._postService.getPosts(this.urlG)
    .subscribe(result =>{ 
      this.actionsG = result; 
      var count = JSON.stringify(result);
      //console.log("value ...." +count);
      ActionsComponent.aCount = count.substring(count.indexOf(','),23);
      console.log(ActionsComponent.aCount);
```

but when trying to access to outside the subscribe it's value it's undefined, and inside the subscribe when i log it, i have the exact value, someone know what's the matter ??

Comment: have you tried debugging the code and see what values you actually get in on the response?

Comment: Where you tried to access variable, try to do it inside `subscribe` function, otherwise you don't know if Json was already processed

Comment: i'm trying to get it actually by substring it ( look up at the question i've update it)

Comment: why are you stringifying the result and not just access it via javascript?

Comment: as i mentionned i've tried accessing it with typescript directly i couldn't do it, so i'm trying right now just to affect the aCount value inside the subscribe

Comment: have you debugged it though? see what you actually get in the result variable, and how it's structured?

Comment: yes when i'm loging the acount value inside the subscribe i'm getting the value,  then i'm setting it to a class variable, and when i'm trying to print the class variable outside of the constructor i'm geting undefined value

Comment: @csharpfolk is most likely right then, you must be trying to access the variable before the http request finishes and thus it is undefined. where/how is it accessed outside the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

> when trying to access to outside the subscribe it's value it's undefined, and inside the subscribe when i log it, i have the exact value, someone know what's the matter

Two possible issues

- Are you sure you have the right `this`? : More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html
- Async stuff happens async. So you need to chain them.